# Reversing a linked list (Java)

Tags: java, performance, linked-list, interview-questions

Triggered by an interview question (I didn't answer during the interview) I wrote a Java program to reverse a linked list. I went with a loop-based approach instead of recursion. I would like to know the following:

- Is the `reverse()` method efficient as it is, or can it be improved?
- Are the inline comments inside the `reverse()` method clear or are they confusing and/or superfluous?

The following is the code for the entire `LinkedList` class I wrote, containing a `public` `reverse()` method:

```
public class LinkedList<T> {
    /**
     * A Node represents a single item inside the linked list. Each node contains
     * the value of the item and a pointer to the next node.
     */
    class Node {
        T value;
        Node next;
    }

    /**
     * The 'head' is the beginning of the linked list.
     */
    Node head;

    /**
     * Add an item to the end of the linked list.
     * 
     * @param value - The value of the item to be added
     */
    public void add(T value) {
        // Create the new node to be added
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.value = value;

        // If list is empty, add it at the head
        if (head == null) {
            head = newNode;
            return;
        }

        // If the list is not empty, find the end of the list and add it there
        Node current = head;
        while (current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = newNode;
    }

    /**
     * Perform an in-place reversal of the elements in the linked list.
     * 
     * After this method is called, the order of the elements in the linked list
     * will be reversed.
     */
    public void reverse() {
        Node current = head;        // Start at the beginning
        Node previous = null;       // In each iteration, points to the current node's previous node
        Node next;                  // In each iteration, we use this to backup the current node's next node
        while (current != null) {
            next = current.next;        // Backup current node's next node
            current.next = previous;    // Point current node backwards - to the previous node
            previous = current;         // Set new previous to current node, for next iteration
            head = current;             // Point head to current, so by end of loop, it will point to the original tail
            current = next;             // Point current to the original next node, for next iteration
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        Node current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            sb.append(current.value + " ");
            current = current.next;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

The following is the code I used to test the above method, just in case it is required:

```
public class LinkedListReversal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);

        System.out.println(list);

        list.reverse();

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your recent edit was ok, however site policy is that code in questions shouldn't be changed after you start getting answers as it can invalidate answers that exist, or are in the process of being written.  Please refrain from editing your code further.  See also: [what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Comment: Perhaps your interview question was phrased so as to exclude this, but if *I* wanted to reverse any kind of `java.util.List` then I would go straight to `Collections.reverse()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Questions

> Is the `reverse()` method efficient as it is, or can it be improved?

You cannot reverse a standard linked list without touching all its nodes, which has a lower-bound asymptotic complexity of o(N) operations.  Your `reverse()` method has O(N) complexity and uses O(1) extra space, so you cannot improve its asymptotic complexity in either of those dimensions.  Note that the usual recursive solution consumes o(N) overhead, all on the stack, so an iterative implementation is clearly a superior choice.

You could, however, make it slightly more efficient by updating `head` just once, at the end, instead of at every iteration.  In particular, instead of `head = current;` inside the loop, you could use `head = previous;` immediately after the loop.  No other changes would be required.

Consider, however, that if speed of the `reverse()` method were of paramount importance, such that it was reasonable to sacrifice a bit of list-traversal performance, then you could create a List class for which `reverse()` is O(1).  I would do that with an internal circular, doubly-linked list of Nodes, with node traversal performed via a Node method that relies on an instance variable of the host List to determine which direction to consider as forward.  With such a structure, (logically) reversing the list would be achieved simply by changing the value of the single variable that controls list direction.  Example:

```
int direction = 0;

class Node {
    T value;
    Node[] links = new Node[2];
    public Node next() {
        assert ((direction >= 0) && (direction < links.length));
        return links[direction];
    }
}

public void reverse() {
    direction = 1 - direction;
}
```

> Are the inline comments inside the `reverse()` method clear or are they confusing and/or superfluous?

They are both clear and largely superfluous.  You've chosen reasonably good names for your variables, so the meaning of the code is fairly well readable from the code itself.  More generally, I rarely think it appropriate to comment every single one of a series of simple statements.  It is more effective to document at a somewhat higher level: if each statement reads well in and of itself then document the purpose of *groups* of lines.

Also, I prefer trailing comments to be very short.  If you have something longer to say then put it on its own line or lines.

### Additional comments

Clearly your `LinkedList` class is constructed for the express purpose of demonstrating `reverse()`, as it is missing methods that one would expect a general-purpose list class to provide.  That might or might not be an issue if you were to present such an answer in an interview.  Note that you could provide a full-featured implementation of `java.util.List` by extending `AbstractSequentialList` and implementing its `listIterator()` method.

On general principles, the inner `Node` class should have a constructor with which its `value` field and maybe its `next` field can be initialized.  It may be appropriate to make the value `final`, too, as @forsvarir also suggested -- this is possible only if you provide a constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The `reverse()` method looks to be fine as per me. As a general comment for a linked list implementation, insertions at the end of list should be taking `O(1)` time complexity.

So the `add()` method can be improved by keeping a pointer to the last node in the list and using it to add the elements to the list.

```
private Node last;
```

Add method can be simplified as

```
public void add(T value) {
    if (last == null) {
        head = new Node(value);
        last = head;
        return;
    }

    last = last.next = new Node(value);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review - you've just gone through the "late Answer" review queue. Note that you need to modify `last` in the "else" part too so that it keeps pointing to the end (add `last = last.next` before returning)

Comment: Nice idea, but you aren't maintaining `last` correctly. Assigning `last.next` is not sufficient; you need to write `last = last.next = new Node(value)`.

Comment: And of course, you would have to maintain `last` consistently in `reverse()` as well. In an interview situation, you might want to just focus on the task at hand, and avoid performance-enhancing complications.

Answer (score 1):

**Comments**

I found some of the comments to be a bit superfluous, for example:

```
// Create the new node to be added
```

The inline comments in the `reverse` method also seemed unnecessary.  If you need to, then explain your algorithm in a single block, but you shouldn't need to comment what every line of your algorithm does.  I'd consider renaming `next` to `nextNodeToProcess` to be more explicit about what the variable is being used for.

**Node**

Once constructed, you don't change the `value` member of your `Node` class.  I'd consider adding a constructor to initialise it and make the member `final`.

Answer (score 1):

**`Node`**

You definitely should declare **`Node`** as

1. **`static`** - which removes an **implicit** reference to enclosing **`LinkedList`** from **all** the nodes;
2. **`private`** - which hides the node type implementation from all the classes that reside in the same package as your **`LinkedList`**.

**Head**

The head node should be declared **`private`**.

**Constructor**

Also, it would make sense to define a constructor that takes the **`value`** and assigns to the relevant field.

**`add()`**

With a new funky node constructor, you can write **`add()`** a little bit more succintly (see **Summa summarum** below).

**`reverse()`** and **`toString()`**

The same comment applies to `reverse` and `toString`.

**Summa summarum**

All in all, I had this in mind:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LinkedList<T> {

    /**
     * A Node represents a single item inside the linked list. Each node contains
     * the value of the item and a pointer to the next node.
     */
    private static final class Node<T> {
        final T value;
        Node next;

        Node(final T datum) {
            this.value = datum;
        }
    }

    /**
     * The 'head' is the beginning of the linked list.
     */
    private Node head;

    /**
     * Add an item to the end of the linked list.
     * 
     * @param value - The value of the item to be added
     */
    public void add(T value) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(value);
            return;
        }

        Node node = head;

        while (node.next != null) {
            node = node.next;
        }

        node.next = new Node(value);
    }

    /**
     * Perform an in-place reversal of the elements in the linked list.
     * 
     * After this method is called, the order of the elements in the linked list
     * will be reversed.
     */
    public void reverse() {
        // The algorithm is basically popping a stack into another one which
        // "reverses" the list.
        Node head2 = null;

        while (head != null) {
            final Node<T> tmp = head; 
            head = head.next;
            tmp.next = head2;
            head2 = tmp;
        }

        head = head2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (head == null) {
            return "[]";
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[").append(head.value);
        Node node = head.next;

        while (node != null) {
            sb.append(", ").append(node.value);
            node = node.next;
        }

        return sb.append("]").toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            final String command = scanner.next().toLowerCase().trim();

            switch (command) {
                case "add":
                    int number = scanner.nextInt();
                    list.add(number);
                    break;

                case "reverse":
                    list.reverse();
                    break;

                case "print":
                    System.out.println(list);
                    break;

                case "quit":
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.